# Search a string in notepad copy and paste to certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am searching for a macro to search a string in notepad. it should search a string ("report") as starting  string and it should end the search in ("end of report").

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadTxtFile()
    Dim start As Date
    start = Now

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim oFS As Object

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt "

    Dim arr(100000) As String
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    If oFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then
        On Error GoTo Err

        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
        Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
            arr(i) = oFS.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        oFS.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(1, arr(i), "report", vbTextCompare) Then
            Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
            Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
            Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", start, Now)

    Exit Sub
```

Error message:

```
Err:
    MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    oFS.Close
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Here I am having the code that search the starting but it should finish "end of the report" as end string copy the whole content what i had searched in the text and paste it in a new notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've enhanced part of your code to include 2 things

(1) to look out for content in between 'report' and 'end of report'

(2) copy the content into a new .txt file called xyz.txt that was saved onto my Z:\ drive

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(1, arr(i), "report", vbTextCompare) Then

        'Declare variables for the new output file
        Dim sOutputFileNameAndPath As String
        Dim FN As Integer
        sOutputFileNameAndPath = "Z:\xyz.txt"
        FN = FreeFile

        'Open new output file
        Open sOutputFileNameAndPath For Output As #FN


        'While 'end of report' has not been found, 
        'keep looping to print out contents starting from 'report'
        Do While InStr(1, arr(i), "end of report", vbTextCompare) = 0

            Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
            Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
            Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

            'Print into new output file
            Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

            'increment count
            i = i + 1

        Loop

        'Print out the 'end of report' line as well
        Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
        Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

        'Print 'end of report' line into new output file as well
        Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

        'close the new output file
        Close #FN

        'exit the 'For..Next' structure since 'end of report' has been found
        Exit For


    End If

Next
```

Comment: Hi cll, if i had to search the same thing with different start points as reports123 and end of the report and i need to search like this report234, report 456, report678 with n number of files present in a folder. can u help me out of this problem